# Holomorphic function with prescribed orders

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to investigate the ring $R$ of holomorphic functions on a Riemann surface $X$ from an algebraic point of view. A consideration on the valuations corresponding to the localization after maximal ideals lead me to the following **complex analytic** question:

**Question:** Are there examples of Riemann surfaces X such that we can prescribe positive integers and points in $X$ such that some holomorphic function has orders (degrees) equal to the prescribed numbers in the given points? If yes, how large can the set of all prescribed points be?

**For instance:** Given distinct points $p_1,...,p_n \in X$ and $n_1,...,n_m \in \mathbb{N}$ can we find some $f \in R$ such that $ord_{p_i}(f) = n_i$ for all $ i \in {1,...,m}$?

**Or:** Can we do this even for infinite families of points etc. ?

I am not so familiar with complex analysis and have therefore no chance to answer this question on my own. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: On a compact Riemann surface, there are no non-constant holomorphic functions.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Are there examples of Riemann surfaces where such things can happen?

Comment: Non-compact RS can have this property, for example if genus is zero. If genus is positive, it depends.

Comment: Interesting! Which statement do you exactly mean?

Comment: Genus zero non-compact RS is just an open set in $\mathbb{C}$, so you can find holomorphic functions with finitely many prescribed zeroes of specified order.

Comment: Do you know, if stronger results are also true?